# Restrict show media files from specific domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have a media server (FTP folder) including .mp4 files and I want to display these media files only through the specific domain or IP and I want to block the download files directly. how can I do that with .htaccess files in my media folders?

I search about that and I found some solution but none of them working in my case.

**1st solution :**

> Order Deny, Allow
>
> Deny from all

```
Allow from 000.000.000.000
```

**2nd solution:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I want to show my media files through a domain (www.mydomain.com) and those files restrict to directly access and just show on web with URL including my domain name.

Comment: For example :

Just link to media ( http:// <IP> /folder-name/media1.mp4) available on my page WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM will work and other links form any pages on web or access directly download are forbidden .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict by IP, add in .htaccess file

```
<Directory /folder>
   Options +Indexes
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 000.000.000.000
</Directory>
```

Comment: this script limit access to files just from that IP.

But I want to show my media files through a domain (www.mydomain.com) and those files restrict to directly access and just show on web with URL including my domain name.